# replacement for roundtrip serialize-deserialize

Tags: c#, json, serialization, constructor

I've a table with over 100 column (including blobs) and I want to make a copy of object only with a few filled columns. 
right now I'm doing it by selecting needed columns and doing a round-trip serialize and deserialize with Json.NET which is not efficient. what's the best way to handle this scenario?

```
BL.Case mCase;
BL.Case temp = db.Cases.Select(
               xx => new
               {
                   CaseID = xx.CaseID,
                   FirstName = xx.FirstName,
                   LastName = xx.LastName
              }).FirstOrDefault(u => u.CaseID == CaseID);

mCase = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<BL.Case>(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(temp));
```

Comment: Serialization is common way of deep-cloning... Quite reasonable approach when you can't for whatever reason create object directly.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't do `db.Cases.FirstOrDefault(u => u.CaseID == CaseID).Select(xx => new BL.Case { CaseID = xx.CaseID... });` ?

Comment: Have you tried [profiling](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms182372.aspx) to determine your actual performance bottleneck?  For instance, if string formatting is taking too much time you could consider round-tripping to [bson](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializeToBson.htm), which is basically binary JSON.

Comment: @meataxe it's not allowed by design, it will throw exception Explicit construction of entity type xxxx in query is not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

Use [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/).

Do something like this:

```
BL.Case mCase = null;
var temp = db.Cases.Select(
                xx => new
                {
                    CaseID = xx.CaseID,
                    FirstName = xx.FirstName,
                    LastName = xx.LastName
                }).FirstOrDefault(u => u.CaseID == CaseID);



if (temp != null)
{
    mCase = Mapper.DynamicMap<BL.Case>(temp);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Automapper improved performance by 100% in small loops (around 100 times ) and it improves performance around 25% in larger loops (100,000 run)

Comment: Do you mean 25% or 2500%? 25% means only 1/4 faster.

Comment: 25% meaning 1/4 faster

Comment: 100,000 objects takes around 5500 milliseconds

Answer (score 0):

Another solution that requires a bit more code (but might perform better) is to do the following:

In case you need a single item:

```
BL.Case mCase = null;
var temp = db.Cases.Select(
            xx => new
            {
                CaseID = xx.CaseID,
                FirstName = xx.FirstName,
                LastName = xx.LastName
            }).FirstOrDefault(u => u.CaseID == CaseID);



if (temp != null)
{
    mCase = new Case()
    {
        CaseID = temp.CaseID,
        FirstName = temp.FirstName,
        LastName = temp.LastName,
    };
}
```

If you need multiple items:

```
var temp = db.Cases.Select(
            xx => new
            {
                CaseID = xx.CaseID,
                FirstName = xx.FirstName,
                LastName = xx.LastName
            }); //Here you can filter your query if you want using Where

var result = temp
.ToList() //This will actually execute the query on the database
.Select(x => new Case() //Now you can do this since now we are working on in-memory data
{
    CaseID = x.CaseID,
    FirstName = x.FirstName,
    LastName = x.LastName
});
```